# PostgreSQL: SELECT * from table WHERE timestamp IS WITHIN THIS MONTH

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

For some reason I'm kind of lost on how to archive:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp IS WITHIN THIS MONTH;
```

I've looked at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html, but are only able to select X days backwards.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: So your table only has 12 months of data; or January of 2017 and January of 2016 should included in the results?

Answer (score 6):

```
... WHERE date_trunc('month', timestamp)
        = date_trunc('month', current_timestamp);
```

Alternatively:

```
... WHERE timestamp >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
      AND timestamp <  date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 month';
```

The second version can use an index on `timestamp`, the first would need one on the expression `date_trunc('month', timestamp)`.

Comment: Is it possible to compare "timestamp > this month".

Comment: build a string so that it's a valid date for current month and then cast it to date.

Comment: something like `WHERE timestamp > to_date('2017-' ||date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) || '-01','YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @MichaelNielsen I don't understand *timestamp > this month*.

Comment: I'm able to get year and month with to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM');, but trying to get unix timestamp fails: select to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM'));

Comment: I still don't understand. Maybe you should tell us what data type your timestamp is. You can get the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970 with `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just filter the month with between ? 
Pass the start of this month as variable1, and the end of this month as variable2...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
timestamp >= __month_start AND timestamp < __next_month_start
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
(
    timestamp >= '20170701'::timestamp 
    AND 
    timestamp < '20170801'::timestamp
)
```

Unlike using functions in the where-clause, this maintains sargability.

Answer (score 0):

What [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) suggested will work, however you're going to have a performance penalty because you'll lose cardinality on that field, you either have to index expression you're going to query (Apparently PostgreSQL allows to do that: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) or create a separate column to store yyyy-mm values and query it.

Comment: The timestamp column is indexed, howeover, im unsure I understand your comment completely. Can you ellaborate?

Comment: @MichaelNielsen Of course I can, if you don't query field directly and apply some sort of functions on it (uppercase, date_trunc like in this case), RDBMS will not use index on that field, so what I suggested is to create an index on field with expression you're going to use or create a dedicated field for better performance.

Comment: @eurotrash I agree, that's also an approach!

Comment: I have the unix_timestamp column also, which are indexed. Would it be possible to do unix_timestamp > some_conversion_to_1st_of_month(current_timestamp) which would be fast and effecient.

Comment: Perhaps, unix_timestamp > to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM') ?

Comment: Or perhaps unix_timestamp > to_timestamp(to_char(unix_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM') and then create an index on to_timestamp(to_char(unix_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYY-MM')

Comment: These are rage scans, try adding a separate field that stores just year and month and compare two it, it's an equality search and should be faster than range query.